# Where is the code or executable for CHSC?

Tags: haskell, compiler-optimization

I have read many papers on the development of the [Cambridge Haskell Supercompiler](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/supercompilation/) and want to try it out and look at the code to understand it more, but I cannot seem to find anything about it besides the papers. There are [some pages](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Supercompilation) on the GHC wiki, but those seem to be outdated. I know that work is still going on, due to [ticket 6070](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6070).

Is there anywhere I can get the source code, or even an executable to try out? If not, when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a fairly regularly updated repository at https://github.com/ghc/ghc/tree/supercompiler. Unfortunately, there seems to be very little documentation, besides that of the stock GHC. This means that it is very difficult to figure out how to use the supercompiler. That said, I haven't tried yet, so it may be easier than it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Simon meant Max Bollingbroke, there is a CHSC repo on his [Github](https://github.com/batterseapower/chsc). I haven't used it before but it seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: This is great, except that the latest commit seems to be from over a year ago. Where could the recent stuff be? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @gereeter You might try emailing Max and ask if anyone else is maintaining a branch.